# Wordpress Calendar Customization

Tags: wordpress

I have translated a theme that I use with WordPress into Tamil, but I can't find where to edit the archive/calendar text, or to be specific, the names of the months. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use[Translating](http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress) for using the other languagess in your wordpress theme.

Else you can study the structure of wordpress to understand its language completely.